# Regex that does not match strings after a specific string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have requirement for a regex that does not match strings after specific string, suppose I have the following string

```
4515856581128483548598852649285965451533568536158523
```

In the above string, I have to replace all the 5s with 0 except the 5s immediate after to 8, as below:

```
4010856081128483048598852649285960401033068536108523
```

I have tried, as below:

```
"4515856581128483548598852649285965451533568536158523".replace(/5(?!8)/g,'0')
"4015806581128483048098802649280960401033068036158023"
```

It replaced all 5's except followed by 8, so I tried:

```
"4515856581128483548598852649285965451533568536158523".replace(/(?!8)5/g,'0')
"4010806081128483048098802649280960401033068036108023"
```

It replaced all 5's. How can I replace all the 5s with 0 except the 5's immediate after to 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below regex

```
.replace(/(85)|5/g, (m, $1) => $1 || '0')
```

The regex will search for `85` or `5`. If `5` followed by 8 is found, no replacement happens. When there is no `85`, the matched `5` will be replaced by `0`.

Note that `$1` here is the value of first captured group i.e. `85` when matched. If `85` is not found, `$1` will be empty string and thus the OR condition will return second value i.e. `'0'`.

```js
console.log('4515856581128483548598852649285965451533568536158523'.replace(/(85)|5/g, (m, $1) => $1 || '0'));
```

Comment: my bad, I have edited my question as it is confusing, could you go through it?

Comment: @sitchie Just change the `58` to `85`.